# Subclass constructor not storing data for object

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, subclass

I am trying to create subclasses of superclass 'Entry' which store information for eg borrowed library items. Using my main to test these results in no values returned for 'name' and 'artist' but it does return a value for the superclass variable 'borrowedBy'. I thought that having them in the constructor would pass the values to the objects but I seem to have made a mistake here somewhere.
 header file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Entry{
private:
    int borrowed;
    std::string borrowedBy;
public:
    Entry();
    void printDetails();
    std::string getborrowedBy();
};

class MusicAlbum : public Entry{
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string artist;
public:
    void printDetails();
    MusicAlbum(std::string name, std::string artist);
    ~MusicAlbum();
    std::string getname();
};
```

cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "C2.h"

MusicAlbum::MusicAlbum(std::string name, std::string artist){
    std::cout << "Constructor..." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Name: " << name << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Artist: " << artist << std::endl << std::endl;
}

MusicAlbum::~MusicAlbum(){};

std::string MusicAlbum::getname(){
    return name;
};

std::string Entry::getborrowedBy(){
    return borrowedBy;
};

Entry::Entry(){
    borrowed = 1;
    borrowedBy = "test1";
};

void MusicAlbum::printDetails(){
    std::cout << "Printer..." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Name: " << name << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Artist: " << artist << std::endl << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    MusicAlbum MA1("Name1", "Artist1");
    MA1.printDetails();
    std::cout << "getname: " << MA1.getname() << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "getborrowedby: " << MA1.getborrowedBy() << std::endl << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Running the program gives the following:

```
Constructor...
Name: Name1
Artist: Artist1

Printer...
Name:
Artist:

getname:

getborrowedby: test1
```

So it would seem that the information from the 'Entry' constructor is being stored, but not the information from the 'MusicAlbum' constructor. 
Secondly, when defining a new object, is it possible to change the value 'borrowedBy' whilst keeping it private? It is 'inaccessible' in the MusicAlbum constructor.

Comment: The `MusicAlbum` constructor doesn't actually assign any of its members. It just `cout`s some stuff.

Comment: Would they not be taken from the arguments because they're named identically?

Comment: No, they wouldn't. It's probably better to learn the language than guess how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your constructor to initialize your class member variables.  Nothing is done automatically because of the name of variables :

```
MusicAlbum::MusicAlbum(std::string name, std::string artist) 
         : name(name), artist(artist) {
     ...
}
```

`name(name)` means to initialize the class member `name` (the outer name) with the argument `name` (the inner name).

Note that this initializer list allows also to specify arguments for the base class.  For instance, if you would have a base constructor:

```
Entry::Entry(std::string borrower) 
    :  borrowedBy(borrower), borrowed(1)
{ };
```

You could then also have a derived constructor like:

```
MusicAlbum::MusicAlbum(std::string name, std::string artist, std::string bywhom) 
         : name(name), artist(artist), Entry (bywhom) {
     ...
}
```